# Split json using NiFi

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I have a json with all the records with merged I need to split the merged json and load in separate database using NiFi

My file when I execute

`db.collection.findOne()`

My input looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "sai",
    "id": 101,
    "company": "adsdr"
  },
  {
    "name": "siva", 
    "id": 102,
    "company": "shar"
  },
  {
    "name": "vanai", 
    "id": 103,
    "company": "ddr"
  },
  {
    "name": "karti",
    "id": 104,
    "company": "sir"
  }
]
```

I am getting all the json. I need to get output as:

`{name: "sai", id:101, company: "sdr"}`

So i only want one record, how can I parse the json using NiFi?

Comment: My json file {  {name: sai, I'd:101,company: adsdr}{name: siva, I'd:102,company: shar}{name: vanai, I'd:103,company: ddr}{name: karti, I'd:104,company: sir}}

Comment: I updated your question for you, i would check you're happy with the edits. In the future you should add important information like example inputs to the actual question and not as a comment. I've ignore the fact that the example JSON isn't valid.

Answer (score 8):

There is a SplitJson processor for this purpose:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html

There are various JSON Path testers online to come up with the correct expression:

https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 4):

Use Split json processor with below configs as shown in the below screenshot

SplitJson Config

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*As Bryan said, you can use [SplitJson processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html)*, and then, you can forward the splitted data flow to other databases. The processor internally using [this](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) json pathfinder. You can read there the operations that the processor supports.

**Just use this to get the first element by:**

```javascript
// JSON Path Expression for the first element:
$[0]

[
  {
    "name": "sai",
    "id": 101,
    "company": "adsdr"
  }
]
```